# Absolute paths (baseUrl) gives error: Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app, absolute-path

I am setting a configuration to run my tests in a create-react-app + typescript app (**from which I have ejected**). I am using jest + enzyme. In my tsconfig.json I have set `baseUrl='./src'` so I can use absolute paths when I import modules. For example this is a typical import statement in one of my files:

```
import LayoutFlexBoxItem from 'framework/components/ui/LayoutFlexBoxItem';
```

You can see that the path is absolute (from /src folder) and not relative. 
This works fine when I run in debug mode ( `yarn start` )

But when I run my test ( `yarn test` ), I get this error:

```
 Cannot find module 'framework/components/Navigation' from 'index.tsx'
```

So it looks like jest is not able to resolve this absolute path although I have set it up in my tsconfig.json. This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src"    
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "dist",
    "config",    
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now I can see that there is a generated `tsconfig.test.json` at the root of my project. This is the ts configuration used for test. And here is its content:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

As you can see the "module" is `commonjs` here whereas in the default configuration it is `esnext`. Could this be one reason?

Has any one been able to unit test his typescript project with Jest and absolute path? or is this a known bug? Since I have ejected from default configuration, are there some settings to put in my webpack configuration?

Thanks for your input and suggestion.

Answer (score 223):

I was struggling with the same problem and actually it turns out that a simple change seems to do the trick.

I just updated the `moduleDirectories` field in `jest.config.js`.

**Before**

```
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules']
```

**After**

```
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src']
```

Comment: I added this inside package.json, under `jest`.

Comment: This may be obvious, but if you include src path in imports like "... from 'src/...'", add this: `moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '.']` instead.

Comment: I added package.json then its works! Thanks

Comment: My issues was in a sub-project of an `aws-cdk` typescript project.  My `jest.config.ts` had no `moduleDirectories` line, but when I added the line in your answer, it worked.

Comment: This worked for me but there's a lingering annoyance in Visual Studio Code where it still red-underlines the absolute imports in my tests. Any suggestions?

Comment: @redcartel add this line to your `.vscode/settings.json` or change the setting in the UI: `"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"`

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk thanks, this definitely works if your `baseUrl` in `tsconfig` is `./`

Comment: Be sure you **re-start your watchers** when updating the config!

Comment: Do not use `"."`, use `"<rootDir>"` instead

Answer (score 104):

As many here pointed out `moduleNameMapper` in `jest.config.js` needs to define paths specified in `tsconfig.json`. For example, if you have paths in `tsconfig.json` defined as follows

```
// tsconfig.json
{
 ...
 "baseUrl": "src",
 "paths": {
    "@alias/*": [ 'path/to/alias/*' ]
 }
 ...
}
```

then your `jest.config.js` needs to provide those paths in `moduleNameMapper` in the following format:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    'roots': [
        '<rootDir>/src'
    ],
    'transform': {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    'moduleNameMapper': {
         '@alias/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/path/to/alias/$1'
    }
};
```

Having that we can improve our `jest.config.js` to convert paths defined in `tsconfig.json` automatically. Here is a [Gist code snippet](https://gist.github.com/timosadchiy/87a5c3799ed44837c4d9de48a02a10bc) for that:

```
// jest.config.js

function makeModuleNameMapper(srcPath, tsconfigPath) {
    // Get paths from tsconfig
    const {paths} = require(tsconfigPath).compilerOptions;

    const aliases = {};

    // Iterate over paths and convert them into moduleNameMapper format
    Object.keys(paths).forEach((item) => {
        const key = item.replace('/*', '/(.*)');
        const path = paths[item][0].replace('/*', '/$1');
        aliases[key] = srcPath + '/' + path;
    });
    return aliases;
}

const TS_CONFIG_PATH = './tsconfig.json';
const SRC_PATH = '<rootDir>/src';

module.exports = {
    'roots': [
        SRC_PATH
    ],
    'transform': {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    'moduleNameMapper': makeModuleNameMapper(SRC_PATH, TS_CONFIG_PATH)
};
```

Comment: Thanks. How does that cope with multiple locations defined for an alias (like `"/opt/*": ["first/*", "second/*"]`)?

Comment: doesn'twork for me `    Could not locate module @/c/utils/http mapped as:
`Update: works with only <rootDir> not <rootDir>/src

Comment: How about in a monorepo, where the project root is used to launch the tests, but the tsconfig and jest config are in one of the subdirs (such as frontend)? Still getting not found errors. I think it is related to <rootDir> resolving.

Comment: I like the makeModuleNameMapper function, but I don't think we should do that honestly. Just my personal opinion. The reason is that it is another code in the code base and even it is simple it may confuse some other developer who will deal with potential future issue. I'm for convention over configuration, but this is the config file.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling for hours with this

Answer (score 62):

Here is how I got moduleNameMapper working.

With the below config in my tsconfig:

```
    "paths": {
      "@App/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "@Shared/*": [
        "src/Shared/*"
      ]
    },
```

Here's the moduleNameMapper:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "@App/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  "@Shared/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/Shared/$1"
}
```

Answer (score 50):

Add this following section in your package.json. after you made the changes don't forget to restart your test watchers.

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "roots": [
      "src"
    ],
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Worked for me when I was running into this issue with the nestjs framework. I made the edit to the package.json and am now able to run my tests with absolute paths.

Comment: After making the changes don't forget to restart your test watcher

Comment: As mentioned, if using NEST framework, this works wonderfully.

Comment: This one also helped me using NestJS, thanks!

Comment: Is this still a working solution for you?

Comment: It works for me in create-react-app eject

Comment: " after you made the changes don't forget to restart your test watchers." lol this was my problem

Answer (score 29):

For me, I just needed to add

```
"modulePaths": ["<rootDir>/src"],
```

to my `jest.config.js` file.

Following answer to modify `moduleDirectories` resulted in this error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation
```

Using:

```
modulePaths: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>/src"],
```

From reading [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulepaths-arraystring) it appears that this a list of additional directories and so `node_modules` is unnecessary.

Comment: Unsure why this answer got downvoted - this is a clean answer that works perfectly with newer versions of jest at the very least (I'm on v27+ here) and is the recommended solution to this issue in the docs itself. The only thing is you don't actually need the `<rootDir>` part in most cases where your jest config is at your project root, `src` works fine too.

Comment: That's it, thank you been scratching my head for the last hour!

Comment: @xyzen Thank you `./src` works as well but not `src`

Comment: This saved me a ton of time! Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice! For me it's `"modulePaths": ["<rootDir>"],` since I like to start my abs paths with `src/`

Comment: This is just my case, I dont use any alias. just the reduced version of ab path

Answer (score 21):

For those using an absolute path but not using named mappings, this worked for me:

```js
# jsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
  }
}
```

```js
# jest.config.js
const config = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>'],
};
```

Comment: This is what I needed

Answer (score 11):

### Solution using the best practice

This error occurs because of using absolute paths in the `import` statements of our TypeScript/Nest.js/Angular projects while using Jest. Fixing it with `moduleDirectories` and `moduleNameMapper` options may solve your problem temporarily but it creates issues with other packages such as this [TypeORM issue](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/321). Also, the creator of the Nest.js framework suggests [here](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/321#issuecomment-588678297) and [here](https://github.com/nestjs/typescript-starter/issues/74) that using absolute paths is a bad practice. TypeScript's official [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#relative-vs-non-relative-module-imports) recommends using relative paths for our own modules.

---

### Absolute path vs Relative path

`import` statement with *absolute path* looks like:

```
import { AuthService } from 'src/auth/auth.service'
```

`import` statement with *relative path* looks like:

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service'
```

---

### VS Code Setting

VS Code by default uses absolute path as shown above, when we auto-import using code completion or <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. We need to change this default setting to use relative paths.

Go to VS Code settings and search for a setting: `Import Module Specifier`. Change it from `shortest` to `relative`.

Now from here on, VS Code will automatically import using the relative paths.

---

### Fixing imports in the project

Now in the project files, look for the absolute paths in the imports that look like the example above and delete them. You will see errors for the packages that you deleted. Simply use the auto-import suggestions and import them back. This time they will be imported using the relative paths. This step may be tedious depending on the size of your project but it's worth it in the long run.

---

Hope that works out! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

ts-jest can resolve this problem perfectly!
https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping#jest-config-with-helper

just modify jest.config.js like this:

```
    const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
    const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.json');
    module.exports = {
        // preset is optional, you don't need it in case you use babel preset typescript
        preset: 'ts-jest',
        // note this prefix option
        moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, /* { prefix: '<rootDir>/' } */)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me:

```
npm i -D jest typescript
npm i -D ts-jest @types/jest
npx ts-jest config:init
```

Then in jest.config.js, here's my setup

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  modulePaths: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>/src"],
};
```

in my case, I do not have any `paths` in `tsconfig.json` but I have `baseUrl` set to `src`

Answer (score 5):

If you have intalled ts-jest you can use an util function called **pathsToModuleNameMapper** to convert the path inside tsconfig.json to your jest.config file:

My jest.config.js file:

```
const { join } = require('path');
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest')
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.json')

/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */

module.exports = {
 rootDir: __dirname,
 setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
 setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/config/env.ts'],

 collectCoverageFrom: ["<rootDir>/src/modules/**/*UseCase.ts"],
 coverageProvider: "v8",
 coverageThreshold: {
   global: {
    lines: 40
   }
 },

 bail: true,
 clearMocks: true,
 displayName: 'unit-tests',
 testMatch: ["<rootDir>/src/modules/**/*.spec.ts"],

 preset: 'ts-jest',
 testEnvironment: 'node',

 modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/src"],
 moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
  prefix: join('<rootDir>', compilerOptions.baseUrl)
 })
};
```

Comment: Should use resetMocks not clearMocks

Comment: I was getting the error ` Cannot find module '~/routes' from 'src/server.ts'` in my integration test directory (outside my src dir) and this solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I use `"baseUrl": "./"` without any aliases in `tsconfig.json`

`moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>']` in `jest.config.ts` worked for me.

Now I can import local modules e.g `import { Hello } from "src/modules/hello"` without any problems.

jest.config.ts

```
/*
 * For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property and type check, visit:
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
 */
export default {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.(t|j)s'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  roots: ['src', 'test'],
  setupFiles: ['dotenv/config'],
  testRegex: ['.*\\.spec\\.ts$'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/**/*.json", "test/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've using React with Typescript, I removed `react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom` from `npm test` and added `jest --watch` as my default test, after I added `jest.config.js` to my project following these instructions https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/testing/jest.html

and I used the the configuration mentioned by @Antonie Laffargue (add/edit property `moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src']`), it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I hope this could help to spare time for some of you.

My problem:

- using create-react-app with typescript
- using absolute paths (src/MyComp) to import components inside other components (e.g. App.tsx)
- it was working on compile/run/build
- it was *not* working on test

I found that the error was due to a different value of the NODE_PATH. So I set it on tests run.

I recreated the issue and the fix in here: [https://github.com/alessandrodeste/...](https://github.com/alessandrodeste/test-typescript-absolute-paths/commit/a1264f32133231ec4e6650880b522a8ff92bcc7e)

I'm not sure if this could bring side effects on tests. Let me know if you have feedback ;)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `moduleNameMapper` feature of jest config.
It will map your custom import namespaces to real module locations.

see official documentation here:

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use moduleNameMapper like this:

moduleNameMapper: {
  ".": "./src"
}
But now my test hangs with this message:

Determining test suites to run...

It looks like moduleNameMapper is used when I have mapped my paths. But in my case I have not mapped any path. I just specified a baseUrl

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Has anyone found a solution? I tried "moduleDirectories": ["src"], but it doesn't work.

Comment: A lot of try-hard here, but I found the solution with `moduleNameMapper`.

Comment: This one worked for me '^src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following to my jest config in **package.json** resolved this problem for me.

```
 "moduleDirectories": [
  "node_modules",
  "src"
]
```

Answer (score 3):

If this happens to you in monorepo here's what fixed the problem for me:

Inside `jest.config.js`

```js
roots: ["<rootDir>packages"],
moduleNameMapper: {
  '@monopre/(.+)$': '<rootDir>packages/$1/src',
},
```

Assuming you have in `tsconfig.json`

```js
"paths": {
  "@monopre/*": ["packages/*/src"],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On my side this worked for me:

I defined my paths in tsconfig.json:

```
"paths": { "@example/*": ["src/example/*"] }
```

After that, jest can't import this modules when a test is runned.

You must add in your jest.config.json the moduleNameMppaer:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {"^@example/(.*)$": [
        "<rootDir>/example/$1"
],}
```

This is the way that I had to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Using Svelte Kit, my solution was:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import pkg from 'ts-jest/utils/index.js';
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = pkg;

const { compilerOptions } = JSON.parse(readFileSync('./tsconfig.json'))

export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/*.test.ts'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
    coverageDirectory: './coverage',
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules'],
    globals: { 'ts-jest': { diagnostics: false } },
    transform: {},
    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' }),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was resolved using the **moduleNameMapper** parameter in **jest.config.ts**

**TEST failed with error:**

```
● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'entities/*some_module*' from '*some_path*'
```

Added a line to the **jest.config.ts** file:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    ...
    'entities/(.*)': "<rootDir>/src/entities/$1"
    ...
}
```

Project settings for this case:

**tsconfig.json** with absolut path

```
...
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
    "*": [
        "./src/*"
    ]
},
...
```

**Project tree:**

```
...
src
 |- app
 |- entities
    |-*some_mudule*
       |- ...
       |- index.ts
 |- featues
 |- widgets
...
.jest.config.ts
.tsconfig.json
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using StitchesJS, the module was not found, the solution was to put this in my jest.config.js

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
"stitches.config": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@stitches/react/dist/index.cjs"}
```

You can adapt according to the module you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a monorepo where each project has its own **tsconfig.json** that extends from the base (root) **tsconfig.json**, and each project has its own **jest.config.js**, and you launch tests from the project root, you should add your moduleNameMapper to the **jest.config.js** in the project **root**.

Eg.

```
backend/
 - tsconfig.json
 - jest.config.js

frontend/
 - tsconfig.json
 - jest.config.js

/
- tsconfig.json
- jest.config.js
```

And your problem is in the jest tests **frontend/** and it has a tsconfig like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["client/src/*"]
    },
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json"
}
```

Then adding this to the **root** jest.config should fix the issue:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/client/src/$1',
  },
```

So in total, something like:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['cdk.out/'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['tests'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/client/src/$1',
  },
};
```

Sort of obvious, but adding this answer since I didn't see this case in the other answers, and monorepos are still a thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old thread but recently, on top of the other suggestions of adding the paths on `"moduleNameMapper":` on `jest.config.js` and `"paths":` on `tsconfig.json`, I also had to ***include*** my test folder so the compiler could recognize it.

So on `tsconfig.json`, add:

```
...
"include": ["src", "__tests__"],
...
```

Hope it helps on someone googling for it