# Unable to run tests because Nest cannot find a module

Tags: nestjs

I have followed the unit test example but I am unable to run a test, i don't know why it doesn't work. I have this following error : `Cannot find module 'src/Application/Auth/Command/LoginCommandHandler' from 'LoginCommandHandler.spec.ts'` but my handler is correctly imported.
Thanks for your help.

Here is my unit test:

```
import { LoginCommandHandler } from 'src/Application/Auth/Command/LoginCommandHandler';
import { UserRepository } from 'src/Infrastructure/User/Repository/UserRepository';
import { EncryptionAdapter } from 'src/Infrastructure/Adapter/EncryptionAdapter';

// ...

const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [LoginCommandHandler, UserRepository, EncryptionAdapter],
    }).compile();

    userRepository = module.get(UserRepository);
    encryptionAdapter = module.get(EncryptionAdapter);
    handler = new LoginCommandHandler(userRepository, encryptionAdapter);
```

Here is my src/Application/Auth/Command/LoginCommandHandler/LoginCommandHandler :

```
export class LoginCommandHandler {
  constructor(
    @Inject('IUserRepository')
    private readonly userRepository: IUserRepository,
    @Inject('IEncryptionAdapter')
    private readonly encryptionAdapter: IEncryptionAdapter,
  ) {}
// ...
```

And here is my AuthModule :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    // ...
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
    { provide: 'IUserRepository', useClass: UserRepository },
    { provide: 'IEncryptionAdapter', useClass: EncryptionAdapter },
    LoginCommandHandler,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jest is having trouble finding the module related to the absolute path you are using to import. You can find more information [at this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51174924/9576186).

In short, you just need to tell Jest about where to look for your modules (either in the `moduleDirectories` field from the `jest.config`, or in the `moduleNameMapper` also in the `jest.config`)

Answer (score 43):

Add this to your jest config in the `package.json` file:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
}
```

Answer (score 17):

### Use relative paths instead of absolute paths

`import` statement with *absolute path* looks like:

```
import { AuthService } from 'src/auth/auth.service'
```

`import` statement with *relative path* looks like:

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service'
```

The creator of the Nest.js suggests [here](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/321#issuecomment-588678297) and [here](https://github.com/nestjs/typescript-starter/issues/74) that using the absolute paths is a bad practice. Also, the [TypeScript's official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#relative-vs-non-relative-module-imports) recommends using relative paths for our own modules. There's also an [ESLint rule](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-absolute-path.md) that explains why absolute paths should be avoided. You need to convert the paths of the import statements in your project to the relative paths as shown above.

---

### Configure VS Code to import using relative paths by default

VS Code by default uses absolute path as shown above, when we auto-import using code completion or <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. We need to change this default setting to use relative paths.

Go to VS Code settings and search for a setting: `Import Module Specifier`. Change it from `shortest` to `relative`. Make sure you change it in the TypeScript option, not just JavaScript.

Now from here on, VS Code will automatically import using the relative paths.

---

That's it! Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the VS Code default settings tip. Super helpful and it sorted my module/testing issues in Nest.

Comment: This was a very useful answer - thank you.

Are there any downsides to using relative paths instead of absolute paths?

Comment: @MichaelJay, None that I'm aware of. In the past, we used to have problems with relative paths when we moved files around. But now the IDEs are gettting smarter, they suggest us to automatically refactor the changed paths.

Answer (score 1):

Extend from @Eliezer's answer
For poeple with Mono repo setup you need to add "src" after "rootDir" like below:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
}
```