# Can not find module 'ngx-store' from service.ts

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-test, angular-testing-library

currently I am running on Angular 9 ,while I am testing My Component using Jest, I am getting an error like "Can not find module 'ngx-store' from service.ts"
and the code showing me which is wrong in service file (cartService).

import {SessionStorageService} from 'ngx-store-9'

there are some services injected into component's constructor .
for that I am writing the code into test component.

beforeEach(()=>{imports:[WebStorageModule],providers:[{provide:cartService,useClass:mockcartService}]
}
What is wrong here.

Comment: Do you import the `WebStorageModule` in your `app.module` (or some other appropriate level). Did you install `ngx-store` correctly?

Comment: @Gunnar B ,yes I have imported WebStorageModule into main app.module . I got this error while running my test cases only and  dependency I am using ngx-store-9 but the error it's saying ngx-store.

Comment: Is this the only import that throws an error (if you have more than that)? Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171412/jest-typescript-absolute-paths-baseurl-gives-error-cannot-find-module

Comment: only this import's error throwing for this test suite..rest of test suites are working fine..Can we mock SessionStorageService  and WebStorageModule ?