# How to configure jest config to use aliases like in storybook config?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

My Next.js project is in TypeScript and in `tsconfig.json` i have set `"baseUrl": "./src"` so then in components i don't need to use `../../../components/Button` and just start with `components/Button`.

For this to work in storybook i have set the `main.js` file like so.

```js
const { TsconfigPathsPlugin } = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin')


module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx|mdx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],

  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.plugins = [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ extensions: config.resolve.extensions })]

    return {
      ...config,
    }
  },
}
```

Right now I'm trying to work out how to do this in Jest Config file (because my tests are failing because of jest not understanding aliases) that sits in root project.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer here: [Jest + Typescript + Absolute paths (baseUrl) gives error: Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171412/jest-typescript-absolute-paths-baseurl-gives-error-cannot-find-module)

Just needed to add this to my `jest.config.js`

```
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
```