# non-relative imports - TypeScript - nothing works

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've read and attempted to apply answers to many variations of this question on SO.
I made a very simple project as PoC, just to finally get `tsconfig.ts` options right.
Nothing works. VSCode highlights an error in my imports w/o changes to config. But, even when VSCode is satisfied this will not run/compile. I don't have any of these issues with non-relative paths in a JS project and have read all documentation around this to no avail.

Environment: TSC 4.6.2, NodeJS 16.13.1, on Mac OS Monterey.

Simple `ts-hello-world` project structure:

```
./
node_modules/
package.json
tsconfig.json
src/
    data/
        string.ts -> exports message
    utils/
        punctuation.ts -> exports exclamation
    main/
        app.ts -> imports message and puncutation and concats to display "Hello, World!"
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0"
  }
}
```

*string.ts*

```
export const message: string = 'Hello, World';
```

*punctuation.ts*

```
export const exclamation: string = '!';
```

*main.ts* (made sure this works with relative paths)

```
import { message } from 'data/string';
import { exclamation } from 'utils/punctuation';

const howdy: string = message + exclamation;
console.log(howdy);
```

*tsconfig.json* In a simple form that satisfies VSCode/works in CMD+Click to follow/open imports.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "data/*": ["data/*"],
      "utils/*": ["utils/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I hope somebody can present a working answer! I've tried to revisit this so many times! I have tried all the answers, including prefixing paths with `@`, rootDir, paths with "src/*" and baseUrl ".", and on and on. I've tried all the accepted answers on all the questions remotely around this. TS documentation didn't help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### tsc + node

With `baseUrl`, you're telling Typescript to base all your modules from a specific directory. Which means they will also be compiled with paths relative to `baseUrl`. It is expected that you then use some bundling tool that does all the resolution magic. But `node` doesn't know anything about this, `node` is not aware of `tsconfig.json`, so it will try to find these modules in the path relative to the script and relative to [`NODE_PATH`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading-from-the-global-folders) env variable.

```sh
$ npx tsc && node src/main/app.js
Error: Cannot find module 'data/string'
```

So the solution would be to pass `NODE_PATH` before running, like this:

```sh
$ npx tsc && NODE_PATH=src node src/main/app.ts
Hello, World!
```

Also, with your current `tsconfig.json`, you don't really need "paths" section. The config I used for tests above:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./src"
    }
}
```

#### ts-node

Now, why doesn't it work with `ts-node`? It should be aware of `tsconfig.json`, right? The reason why it doesn't work "out-of-the-box", is explained in their docs:

- https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/paths/

> This means "paths" are intended to describe mappings that the build tool or runtime already performs, not to tell the build tool or runtime how to resolve modules. In other words, they intend us to write our imports in a way node already understands. For this reason, ts-node does not modify node's module resolution behavior to implement "paths" mappings.

But they have a solution for this, you should install `tsconfig-paths` plugin and add it to the `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "ts-node": {
    // Do not forget to `npm i -D tsconfig-paths`
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

```sh
$ npm i -D tsconfig-paths
added 5 packages, and audited 23 packages in 2s

$ npx ts-node src/main/app.ts
Hello, World!
```

Comment: The bottom two code blocks were really what I needed! So awesome!!! Now, I've applied this to a large project and everything is wonderful... until running CI using Jest and *BOOM!* Figured I might ask here for pointers on `jest.config.js` settings to play well with my new changes?

Comment: I am not very good at setting up jest, but I found a similar question here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50171412/361687 - maybe it will help! :)